# onkeyup is not working in jQuery Validate for tinymce

Tags: jquery, validation, tinymce, onkeyup

For validation the form I use the plugin JQuery Validation (jquery.validate.js) with the additional-methods.js. This form contains many inputs in which the fields to be filled out are checked. I use the onkeyup rule for the fileds. Everything works, but does not work the rule onkeyup for tinymce. What needs to be registered so that it works?

```
jQuery(function ($) {
        var validator = $("#adminForm").submit(function() {
            // update underlying textarea before submit validation
            tinyMCE.triggerSave();
        }).validate({
    onkeyup: function(element) {
        this.element(element);  // <- "eager validation"
    },
    onfocusout: function(element) {
        this.element(element);  // <- "eager validation"
    },
            ignore: "",
            rules: {
                title: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 10,
                    maxlength: 50
                },
                donate: {
                    required: true,
                    digits: true,
                    min: 1,
                    max: 60000
                },
                text: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 250
                },
                checkbox: {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                title: {
                    required: "enter the title",
                    minlength: "no less than 10 symbols",
                    maxlength: "no more than 50 symbols"
                },
                donate: {
                    required: "enter the number",
                    digits: "Not a number",
                    min: "no less than 1",
                    max: "no more than 60000"
                },
                text: {
                    required: "here is your text",
                    minlength: "no less than 250 symbols"
                },
                checkbox: {
                    required: "do you public spam?"
                }
            },
            errorPlacement: function(label, element) {
                // position error label after generated textarea
                if (element.is("textarea")) {
                    label.insertAfter(element.next());
                } else {
                    label.insertAfter(element)
                }
            }
        });
        validator.focusInvalid = function() {
            // put focus on tinymce on submit validation
            if (this.settings.focusInvalid) {
                try {
                    var toFocus = $(this.findLastActive() || this.errorList.length && this.errorList[0].element || []);
                    if (toFocus.is("textarea")) {
                        tinyMCE.get(toFocus.attr("id")).focus();
                    } else {
                        toFocus.filter(":visible").focus();
                    }
                } catch (e) {
                    // ignore IE throwing errors when focusing hidden elements
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you load TinyMCE the editor area is actually an `iframe` and not part of the main page so events like `keyup` are not happening in the main page but in the `iframe`.  You can certainly add event handling to the `iframe` as well but this is why you are not seeing these events triggered based on typing in the editor.

Comment: Well, what solution would you recommend? What exactly needs to be done?